# Grunt usemin works with html and css, but not js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-usemin, angular-fullstack

I am trying to use usemin with multiple client html files. I am adding the usemin functionality of each client through a for loop.

I got the following HTML and CSS approaches to work:

```
initConfig.usemin[key+'-html'] = {
  options: {
      assetsDirs : [
        clients[key].dist,
        clients[key].dist+'/assets/images',
        clients['shared'].dist,
        clients['shared'].dist+'/assets/images'
      ],
      type:'html',
      patterns: {
        js: [
          [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
        ]
      }
  },
  files: {
      src: [
          clients[key].dist+'/{,*/}*.html'
      ]
  }
};
initConfig.usemin[key+'-css'] = {
  options: {
      assetsDirs : [
        clients[key].dist,
        clients[key].dist+'/assets/images',
        clients['shared'].dist,
        clients['shared'].dist+'/assets/images'
      ],
      type:'css',
      patterns: {
        js: [
          [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
        ]
      }
  },
  files: {
      src: [
          clients[key].dist+'/{,*/}*.css'
      ]
  }
};
```

Unforunately I can't get this JS one to work:

```
initConfig.usemin[key+'-js'] = {
  options: {
      assetsDirs : [
        clients[key].dist,
        clients[key].dist+'/assets/images'
      ],
      type:'js',
      patterns: {
        js: [
          [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
        ]
      }
  },
  files: {
      src: [
          clients[key].dist+'/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
  }
};
```

I get the following error:

`Warning: Unsupported pattern: js Use --force to continue.`

Any ideas?

I have tested the solution mentioned here works with one client, but I am using multiple clients with their own index.html files and get the same error mentioned above:

[How to let grunt usemin update the JS to reference our revved images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919027/how-to-let-grunt-usemin-update-the-js-to-reference-our-revved-images)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let grunt usemin update the JS to reference our revved images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919027/how-to-let-grunt-usemin-update-the-js-to-reference-our-revved-images)

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos Nope, because mine has multiple targets.